# How Can I Terminate a Thread Using a Throw Exception Method - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I found some code online that will stop a thread via an exception after a wait period of some time.

```
def raise_exception(self):
  thread_id = self.get_id()
  res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 
          ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)) 
  if res > 1: 
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread_id, 0) 
    print('Exception raise failure')
```

An exception is called after some time by:

```
t1 = thread_with_exception('Thread 1') 
t1.start() 
time.sleep(1/1000) 
t1.raise_exception() 
t1.join()
```

I would like to call an exception that would specify how many time a process occurs. Such as:

```
t1 = thread_with_exception('Thread 1') 
t1.start() 
if t1.count >= 3: 
    t1.raise_exception() 
    t1.join()
```

This however fails to call an exception when t1.count >= 3.

Can an exception not be called in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling the raise_exception outside the class, calling it from within the run method for the thread will work. Ex.

```
def run(self):
    if count>3:
         self.raise_exception()
```